# How many times does my site show up on Google search results?

Tags: search, google-analytics, yahoo, bing

Is there any way possible to know how many times my website is showing up on Google's (or Bing's, or Yahoo's) search results, regardless of page rank or whether or not a user clicks the link to my site?

Comment: You can check the referrer, see if it's a search engine.

Comment: That would only be if a user clicked through to my site, right?

Comment: Yeah.  That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: Actually, regardless or traffic to the site, I simply want to know how many times the link to the site is served.